# How can I build a new Diem widget?

Tags: symfony, diem-cms

I want to build a new Diem widget with a back-end part. Like I'd like to be able to add new photos and their descriptions and also change and delete them. Where can I read how to do it?

Comment: Well google is you best friend. Here on Stack Overlow we can just assist, we cant do it for you. So research a bit and come back with some more explicit question + some code ( we love code )

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do it using dmGallery:

http://diem-project.org/diem-5-0/doc/en/reference-book/doctrine-behaviors#dmgallery